# Apply powertop settings

Tags: power-management, intel, tlp, powertop

On the [powertop](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Powertop) page of archlinux wiki it says:

> There are two ways to automatically apply the suggested settings:
>
> - **Recommended**: You can apply these settings at boot by using module parameters, udev rules and sysctl. For details, see the power
>   management page.
> - You can use the --auto-tune feature from powertop which sets all tunable options to their GOOD setting. This can be combined with
>   systemd service to have the tunables set on boot. Remember to
>   enable/start the service.

Currently I use the second method.

I have 3 questions:

1. Will the results be identical?
2. Why is the first way the recommended one?
3. How exactly to implement the first method?

---

Also, a comment on this post [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/7ebqd8/tip_use_powertop_autotune/) says:

> No need to install powertop, just install and run TLP. Feel free to check the variables in powertop afterwards, they'll already be activated by TLP. :-)

If I already use `tlp` does it mean that it applies the powertop sugegsted settings by itself? Or, to ask differently: do I need `powertop` if I use `tlp`?

---

On the TLP webpage there is a [note](https://linrunner.de/tlp/faq/powertop.html):

> On the other hand, attempting to run `powertop --auto-tune` on each boot may overwrite TLP’s settings depending on the actual boot order.

Is it a bad idea to apply powertop settings at boot?

Comment: There's a whole section in the TLP FAQ about Powertop: https://linrunner.de/tlp/faq/powertop.html

Comment: I have a question in the post about that. Why would `powertop --auto-tune` on boot overwrite TLP’s settings?

Comment: That's because TLP and powertop (like all other PM tools) change the same set of kernel settings.

Comment: And that shouldn't be a problem, right? Because "TLP’s default configuration is based on the same policy as Powertop’s recommendations".

Comment: Wrong. On battery the settings are similar, but TLP uses different, less aggressive settings on AC. Plus TLP re-applies it's AC or BAT profile on every change of power source. It's counterproductive to use two tools at the same time.

Comment: The following [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/9724vh/xps_9560_fedora_28_guide_for_power_saving_and_no/) says "TLP is great, but Powertop has the deadly weapon: **the ability to power down the Nvidia card** - which is not used since TLP blacklists the nouveau driver anyway". Would you recommend Powertop for this reason?

Comment: The poster forgot to say that one may re-enable Runtime PM for the Nvidia with TLP as well: https://linrunner.de/tlp/faq/powercon.html

Powertop is a fine analysis tool, but there are downsides:

 * --autotune is not configurable, it just enables every power saving feature, regardless of related problems
 * It doesn't handle USB devices plugged after boot
 * There is no distinction between AC and BAT

Btw: in any case an Nvidia card is deadly for Linux power consumption ... ;)